# How to limit templated function instantiation to certain type when call site is in the same file as function template definition?

Tags: c++, templates

```
// I only wanted these functions be used for certain types, e.g., say, int and float
template <typename T>
void func() {

}


void another_function() {
  func<int>(); // works
  func<float>();  // works
  func<string>(); // I want this to not compile
}
```

I think adding explicit instantiation in this file does not work because `func` and `another_function` are in the same translational unit. Is there another approach to handle this situation?

Comment: C++ 20 concepts would be one way among many ways... SFINAE is another. Explicit specialization should works provide that definitions are before `another_function` but you would get a linker error for the missing definition.

Comment: @Phil1970 hmm, I didn't get any linker errors and I did provide the explicit specialization before `another_function` .this code compiles:
`template <typename T>
void func() {}

template void func<int>();


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  func<double>();
}`

Comment: **Obviously** if the main specialization is defined, you won't get a linker error. **You do almost exactly the opposite of what I explain** : your `int` specialization is not defined while the main one is.

Comment: @Phil1970 Sorry, I keep getting template terms confused. I mixed up "specialization" and "instantiation." I believe I was doing an instantiation in my case and not a specialization